# How to pass the domain name in the URL while handing the authentication window using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium

Ok, so we know that there are several ways to handle Basic authentication pop up using Selenium like by integrating with tools like AutoIT, robot etc and by using Alert class but I am interested in a solution of passing the value in the url itself as I need to run my test on headless browser and I don't think solution like AutoIT or Alert will work in headless.

So, I am using the below syntax to handle the authentication window in Selenium

```
driver.get("http://UserName:Password@mydomain.com");
```

But I need to pass the domain name as well in the above command but whenever I am using the below syntax, it is giving me an error that the page not found

```
driver.get("http://mydomainname\\UserName:Password@mydomain.com");
```

Currently I am using chrome but my guess is if above solution works in Chrome then it should work in Headless browser as well.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Instead of \\ have you tried Passi g /

Comment: yes it is not working.

Comment: are you trying to handle authentication pop-up? try using selenium's AuthenticateUsing() method then.

Comment: AuthenticateUsing() only works in IE and not in Chrome.

Comment: @Naseem: Do you find any solution for this question?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
driver.get("http://mydomainname%5cUserName:Password@url.com");
```

Ensure that the 'url.com' here in this example is the url that appears on the browser when the authentication pop-up turns up.